# Unknown column error where column is a session variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a *really* weird error for a query. I'm working on a CMS and the query works perfectly when I'm in the public pages and, until a couple of hours ago, it also worked in the admin pages.

The weird thing is, when I go to login to admin, it's failing due to a reference to an unknown column which isn't actually a part of the query at all, it's a session variable.

The query is;

```
select * from pages p, templates t, sites s where p.page_title_csv='uber,admin' AND p.page_template_id=t.template_id AND s.site_id=p.page_site_id
```

The error is;

```
Page selection query failed coz of:Unknown column 'this_site' in 'where clause'
```

The column it's referring to ('this_site') is in fact one of my session variables and isn't mentioned in the query at all so how it's causing the error is a total mystery to me. It's not even a column in any of my tables.

I've already checked;

- the database is connecting fine
- there is definitely a page with a page_title_csv of "uber,admin" (and definitely only one)
- I've tried removing the aliases
- I've even tried changing the 'like' to '='
- Destroying $_SESSION and starting again after closing multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari)
- Restarting all services (running Windows 7,Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.3.5 & MySQL 5.5.8)

I know I haven't altered the table structures recently enough to have caused any problems. As I say, it works fine on all of the public pages but not on any of the admin.

The only possible clue I've got left is that $_SESSION['this_site'] has one setting for the public pages while the admin ones have a different value, although why that should matter when it's not even in the query is beyond me (especially when it was fine up until now).

Any help appreciated, it's 3:30am here so giving up for the night before I make things worse... Cheers

(Last ditch is to try a full reboot, if I'm not posting here again within the hour, that didn't work either)

Comment: Could you post your PHP-code for creating and executing the query? The error might lie there.

Comment: The query you posted has no reference to `this_site` which, since you stated it is a session variable, is probably not being parsed (IE not concatenated or used within single quotes). You are going to have to show the relevant code to get some assistance, as you have given great information, just not the "right" information needed to solve your problem.

Comment: The error may not be related to the posted query string at all, but is part of some other part of the CMS as part of validation/verification sequence, so the actual error is caused by a completely DIFFERENT query.

Comment: there may be typo change change `,` with `.` in `where p.page_title_csv='uber,admin'`

Comment: $query="";
$query="select * from pages p, templates t, sites s where p.page_title_csv='".$pagetitle."' AND
p.page_template_id=t.template_id AND s.site_id=p.page_site_id";
echo $query;
testarray($_SESSION);
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Page selection query failed coz of:".mysql_error());
while ($line=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {foreach($line as $col_key => $col_value)
  {$page_values[$col_key]="$col_value";}
 }
mysql_free_result($result);

Comment: Sorry, it took out the line formatting in the code there. The code is falling down before it gets to the "while" but I included it just in case. 
(Marc - this is the first query executed, but I suspect you're right about the error being earlier. Unfortunately, there's about 15 includes (which work fine on public pages) to check - I'm working through those now, disabling and re-enabling etc.)
(And to diEcho - the ',' is in the field value - nice idea though, thanks for the suggestion)

Comment: The $pagetitle is set with;
$_SESSION['current_page']="uber,admin";
as almost the only line in admin.php before it goes to the builder where it fails. The builder sets the page with;
if (isset($_SESSION['current_page'])) {$pagetitle=$_SESSION['current_page'];}
else{$pagetitle="main,contents";}

Comment: @Simon: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!
Marc pointed the way - I started looking further down the line and found that an embedded function in the page was causing the dodgy query because I had changed the way I handled call_user_func() in the page building routines. I'm sure I would have been stuck for much longer if not for the help. (Just writing up my question helped me get it right in my head too, never underestimate the power of writing problems down lol).

Thanks all for viewing/pondering this problem- almost every other problem I've had in the last few months has been solved by just browsing Stackoverflow but this was the first time I had to post. The best site for programmer community help ever and that's partly your fault for reading and responding where you can - thank you one and all!